# Css tamaño de Pantalla, No aplica Boostrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Estoy usando Bootstrap 4 con sus rows y sus col `col-sm-*` , etc.

Esto ayuda en el width si el dispositivo es de "x" tamaño a lo ancho, pero a lo largo del dispositivo lo deja realmente mal.

Os paso unas capturas aunque no se puede ver realmente lo lejos o pequeños que se ven los elementos en un móvil.

Necesito alguna forma en función del alto de la pantalla poder centrar, agrandar etc... como hace el bootstrap con width pero con height o con elementos individuales.

Al ver esto desde un ordenador, puede parecer que el tamaño de los botones son "normales" , pero desde el móvil son realmente enanos y si lo ejecuto en localhost desde mi Pc se ve perfecto.

La resolución de mi pantalla de ordenador es de `1920*1080` y la del móvil es de `1080*1920`.

No necesito un código, sólo saber como solucionar estos problemas ,alguna idea o desde vuestra experiencia que es lo que soleis hacer.

[image: Entrada]
[image: login]

Aquí pongo el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Usuario Estandar</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!--     <meta name="viewport" content="height=1920, initial-scale=3.0">  -->

  <!--- Mis estilos css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette|Fira+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estiloUsuarios.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/sly.horizontal.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/sly.vertical.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="jqueryui/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryui/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryui/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryui/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryui/modernizr.js"></script>

  <!--- AÑADIDO ESTE META --->
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="<?php csrf_token(); ?>">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- CABECERA  -->
  <div class="row opcionesbuton" style="background-color: #0277AE;">

    <!-- LOGO  -->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-2">
      <img alt="Icono" class="logo" src="fotos/LogoHome.jpg">
    </div>

    <!-- FRASE FAVORITA  -->
    <div class="play col-6 col-sm-3 col-xl-1">
      <input type="image" class="MiImg" id="" alt="boton ver frases favoritas" title="frases favoritas" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" src="fotos/favo.png" onclick="mostrarfrase();" />
    </div>

    <!-- PLAY  -->
    <div class="MiImg play col-6 col-sm-3 col-xl-1">
      <input type="image" class="MiImg" id="" alt="boton reproducir frase" title="Reproducir frase" src="fotos/playnegro.png" onclick="sonido();" />
    </div>
    <!-- AÑADIR  -->

    <div class="MiImg play col-6 col-6 col-sm-3 col-xl-1">
      <input type="image" class="MiImg" id="" alt="boton añadir frase a favoritos" title="añadir a favoritos" src="fotos/add.png" onclick="guardarFrase();" />
    </div>

    <!-- AYUDA  -->
    <div class="MiImg play col-6 col-6 col-sm-3 col-xl-1">
      <input type="image" class="MiImg" id="" alt="Ayuda" title="Mensaje de Ayuda" src="fotos/detective.png" />
    </div>

    <!-- Borrar uno  -->
    <div class="MiImg play col-6 col-6 col-sm-3 col-xl-1">
      <input type="image" class="MiImg" id="" alt="boton borrar seleccionado" title="borrar selecionado" src="fotos/eraser.png" onclick="eliminaSeleccionadas();" />
    </div>

    <!-- Borrar todos  -->
    <div class="MiImg play col-6 col-6 col-sm-3 col-xl-1">
      <input type="image" class="MiImg" id="" alt="boton borrado integro" title="borrar todo" src="fotos/deletenegro.png" onclick="eliminaTodo();" />
    </div>

    <!-- Buscar  -->
    <div class="Bajar play col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
      <form class="form-horizontal" id="buscador" method="post">
        <div class="form-group  row">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
          <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3">
            <input type="image" id="" alt="barra buscador" title="buscar" class="MiImg" src="fotos/lupausuario.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-9 col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-xl-8">
            <input id="fname" name="categoria" type="text" placeholder="Búsqueda" class="form-control longitudbarra">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- FIN  Buscar  -->

    <!--CERRAR SESIÓN  -->
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-3 col-xl-1">
      <a class="nav-link" href="cerrar" title="Cerrar Sesion" style="color:white;"><img alt="boton cerrar sesion" title=" cerrar sesion" class="MiImg" src="fotos/powernegro.png"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- FIN  CERRAR SESIÓN  -->

  </div>
  <!-- FINAL DE LA CABECERA  -->


  <!-- FRASES FAVORITAS -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%; margin: 0px;">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="display: initial;">
          <input type="image" onclick="cerrarfrase();" id="xcierre" title="" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" src="fotos/cerrar.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- FIN FRASES FAVORITAS -->

  <!--  SLIDER VERTICAL   -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2 contenedorficha">
        <div class="wrapv">
          <!--  barra vertical -->
          <div class="scrollbar">
            <div class="handle">
              <div class="mousearea"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Las categorías  -->
          <div class="frame smart" id="smart">
            <ul class="items">
              <?php
                                    if (isset($categoria)) {
                                        foreach ($categoria as $valor) {
                                            echo '<li class="ficha">';
                                            echo '<form  method="post" class="cate">';
                                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="' . csrf_token() . '">';
                                            echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $valor->id_categoria . '" id="categoria" name="categoria" />';
                                            echo '<input type="image" id="" title="buscar" class="img-responsive" src="' . $valor->imagen . '"/>';
                                            //echo '<img id="" class="cate "title="buscar" class="img-responsive" src="'.$valor->imagen.'" value="'.$valor->id_categoria.'">';
                                            echo '<p>' . $valor->descripcion . '</p>';
                                            echo '</form>';
                                            echo '</li>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- Fin las categorías  -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Fin Slider Vertical -->

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-xl-10">
        <!-- Este div pondrá al tablero y sliderhorizontal posicionados -->
        <!-- TABLERO -->

        <div class="wraph">
          <div class="tablero">
            <div id="botonGrande"><img src="fotos/cambiar.png"></div>
            <div id="fichatablero" class="row"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- FIN TABLERO -->

        <!-- SLIDER HORIZONTAL -->
        <div class="wraph offset-xl-2 col-xl-10">
          <div class="scrollbar">
            <div class="handle">
              <div class="mousearea"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="frame" id="centered">
            <ul class="clearfix" id="ficha"></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FINAL SLIDER HORIZONTAL -->
      </div>
      <!-- FINAL DivEnglobador -->
    </div>
    <!-- FINAL ROW -->
  </div>
  <!-- FINAL CONTAINER -->

  <!-- Código Ajax y Sliders-->
  <script src="AjaxUsuario.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryui/jquery.plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryui/sly.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryui/sly.vertical.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryui/sly.horizontal.js"></script>
  <!--FIN Código Ajax y Sliders-->

</body>

</html>
```

También tengo otro problema, en el ordenador poniendo en firefox desarrollo web y poniéndolo para `1280*800` se ve perfecto y en una tablet de esa resolución no se ve igual que en mi ordenador, y tengo los `col-xl-` para que haga lo que tiene que hacer (que se vea como en mi ordenador).

[image: desde mi Pc]
[image: desde la tablet]

*La tablet está cogiendo el `col-12` como si fuese menor a 576 porque en la cabecera se ven los elementos UNO en cada fila referente a `col-12*` pero yo mis elementos tienen `col-6` para que salgan de 2 en 2. Es como sino se estuviese aplicando el bootstrap.

Más arriba se puede ver como tiene los `col-6`

```html
<!-- LOGO  -->
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-2">
  <img alt="Icono" class="logo" src="fotos/LogoHome.jpg">
</div>

<!-- FRASE FAVORITA  -->
<div class="play col-6 col-sm-3 col-xl-1">
  <input type="image" class="MiImg" id="" alt="boton ver frases favoritas" title="frases favoritas" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" src="fotos/favo.png" onclick="mostrarfrase();" />
</div>

<!-- PLAY  -->
<div class="MiImg play col-6 col-sm-3 col-xl-1">
  <input type="image" class="MiImg" id="" alt="boton reproducir frase" title="Reproducir frase" src="fotos/playnegro.png" onclick="sonido();" />
</div>
<!-- AÑADIR  -->
```

¿ Alguien sabe qué está pasando ?

Comment: Has probado usar la unidad relativa `vh`? Por ejemplo `80vh` son 80% de la altura de la ventana (viewport height). Tambien existe `vw` (viewport width).

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="height=1920, initial-scale=3.0"> 

No hace nada...

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo que estas usando, para poder ver que error puedes estar cometiendo y asi ser mas claro en una respuesta

Comment: Ya está el código puesto y tengo problemas porque no lo visualizo igual en una tablet que en mi ordenador con la misma resolución.

Comment: Has probado a controlar los col-lg-* = a todos los col-xl-* ?, da la casualidad que el cambio de lg a xl es 1200 y como haya 1 pixel de menos en la tablet no este controlado por el xl y haga lo que quiere, yo crearia reglas de col-lg-* con los mismos valores de xl

Answer (score 0):

A veces puede ser porque en **tu head no tienes el meta de viewport**, coloca esta línea tal cual:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Esa línea ya estaba , es la que te pone por defecto Netbeans al crear un proyecto, la cambié para ver si con heigth=1920 hacía algo.

Comment: 2 Cosas, te sugiero 1: Crear un [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y 2: agregar este código a tu ejemplo. Tal vez creas que es la mejor manera de poner el código, pero esta muy disperso, en tu caso la mejor forma para ayudarte, sería que teclees **`Ctrl + M`** y añadas tu código en la ventana que aparece.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que estás usando la grilla de Bootstrap para hacer un menú, lo cuál no es muy recomendable ya que tendrías que aplicarle varias clases dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla, además de hacer uso de CSS puro para que dé un resultado aceptable.

Lo más recomendable es que uses el componente que nos da bootstrap para hacer menús, que es el `navbar`
Aquí una muestra de como se usa:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    
    <!-- Aquí empieza el código del menú -->
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
    
    <!-- Aquí termina el código del menú --> 

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si cambiar el tamaño de la pantalla, te darás cuenta que se ajusta perfectamente a los tamaños.

Más información en: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/